# Can I build a basic Data Dictionary for Trimble Terrasync without Pathfinder Office?

Tags: data, pathfinder, terrasync

I don't have Pathfinder Office.  Can I build a simple Data Dictionary for Terrasync without it?  I seem to remember a friend once telling me that there is a way to build a data dictionary within the Trimble.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Need a bit more information on what you are trying to accomplish. What have you tried so far?